# Java.lang.RuntimeExeption:Unable to instantiate activity componentInfo:Fragment cannot be cast to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know many such questions have been asked regarding this issue but still after searching a lot i am unable to get rid of it. 
Here is my Fragment code from which i want to call SurfaceView. mv is the object of the class that is extending surfaceView.

```
    public class Stream extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnClickListener{

      private static final String TAG = "MjpegActivity";
      private MjpegView mv;
      Home1 context;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mv = new MjpegView(this.getActivity());
        if(mv!=null)
        {
          Log.i("st","mv");
        }
      }

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       // String URL = "" ;
       new DoRead().execute(URL);
       return mv;
      //return new MjpegView(getActivity());
    }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


     public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       if(mv!=null){
         mv.stopPlayback();}
    }

  public class DoRead extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MjpegInputStream> {
    protected MjpegInputStream doInBackground(String... url) {
        //TODO: if camera has authentication deal with it and don't just not work
        HttpResponse res = null;
        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        // credentials
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.setCredentialsProvider(provider);


        Log.d(TAG, "1. Sending http request");
        try {
            res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url[0])));
            Log.d(TAG,url[0]);
            Log.d(TAG, "2. Request finished, status = " + res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            if(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==401){
                //You must turn off camera User Access Control before this will work
                return null;
            }
            return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());  
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Request failed-ClientProtocolException", e);
            //Error connecting to camera
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Request failed-IOException", e);
            //Error connecting to camera
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(MjpegInputStream result) {
        mv.setSource(result);
        mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);
        mv.showFps(true);
    }
}
```

}

Adapter for fragments:

```
    public class TabsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
     public TabsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
     }
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new CamsList();
    case 1:
        return new Stream();
    case 2:
        return new Settings();
    }
    return null;
  }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

}

Here is my LogCat:

```
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622): java.lang.RuntimeException:      Unable to instantiate activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.surveillanceapp/com.example.surveillanceapp.Stream}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.surveillanceapp.Stream cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
   07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2001)
   07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
   07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
   07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
   07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.surveillanceapp.Stream cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
    07-09 11:36:25.141: E/AndroidRuntime(25622):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my manifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.surveillanceapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.DownloadJSON"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_download_json" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.example.app.DownloadJSON" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.Home1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.TabsPageAdapter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tabs_page_adapter" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.CamsList"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cams_list" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.Settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.Stream"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_stream" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.VerfifyLogin"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_verfify_login" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.DownloadJSON" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.GenerateAlarmService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.VerifyLogin" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.StopAlarmService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.MessageSendingService" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.CustomAdapter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_adapter" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.GsmSettings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gsm_settings" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.MessageSendingService"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_message_sending_service" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.ObjectDrawerItem"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_object_drawer_item" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.DrawerItemCustomAdapter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_drawer_item_custom_adapter" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.HelpFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help_fragment" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.Help"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.AboutUs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.StopAlarmService"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_stop_alarm_service" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.GenerateAlarmMsg"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_generate_alarm_msg" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.GenerateAlarmService"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_generate_alarm_service" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.SpeechRecog"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_speech_recog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.BroadcastNewSms"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_broadcast_new_sms" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.ViewNotification"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_notification" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Consructor in surfaceView is receing the context which i have to pass from the Fragment. I also tried by passing the context to AsyncTask, by overriding the onAttach() method of fragment. Then i made changes to my code by following a tutorial still i am getting this error.

Comment: Post your `manifest.xml` file plz..

Comment: post your code for com.example.surveillanceapp.Stream

Comment: remove `<activity
        android:name="com.example.surveillanceapp.Stream"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_stream" >` from `manifest.xml` becoz `Stream` is not an `Activity`. It's an `Fragment`.

Comment: @MD the issue is still there. CamsList and Settings are also fragments. I am getting an error when i tap the item in CamsList fragment and that needs the surfaceView.

Comment: I think the problem should be in your `Activity`. It seems you are trying to use a `Fragment` like `Activity`

Comment: i figured out the problem. @Joseph82 you were right i was starting fragment as an activity. Can u plz tell me how to start the fragment from another fragment. I searched it but i got stuck at FragmentTransaction.replace() method. Any help plz?

Comment: Take a look at the [Fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). In the section "Adding a fragment to an activity" you'll find two ways for starting the fragment: 1) Declare the fragment inside the activity's layout file. Or 2) programmatically add the fragment to an existing.